# R: Why is a not data.table assigned data.frame automatically DT?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.frame, here an example:

```
df <- data.frame(object = c("apples","tomatoes", "apples","pears" ),
                 Value = c(50,10,30,40))
```

I make a copy of this df to keep it in format data.frame:

```
forDT <- df
```

And the new copied data.frame I assigned to data.table performing a split of the data:

```
require(data.table)
tmp = setDT(forDT)[, list(grp=list(.SD)), by=.(object), .SDcols=names(forDT)]
setattr(import_split <- tmp$grp, 'names', paste(tmp$object, sep="."))
```

In the following step I need the original data.frame which I didn't convert into data.table for further calculations (as I am more familiar with data.frames, thats why I made the copy in the beginning). However, the original `df` is also of data.table format. What I'm doing wrong? Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Use `as.data.table` instead of `setDT`. Using `setDT` doesn't create a copy.

Comment: `forDT <- df` doesn't create a copy.. Use `copy()` from data.table package. Or use `as.data.table()` as mentioned by Ananda Mahto. Also have a look at the [Reference Semantics](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) vignette.

Comment: Isn't a `data.table` still a `data.frame`, though? Why making a copy to *preserve* it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set*` functions in "data.table" do not make copies of your data.

To make a copy, you should use `as.data.table` or use the `copy` function from the "data.table" package.

Comment: I guess it's not just that `set*` doesn't make a copy (which the OP might already know/expect), but also that `forDT <- df` doesn't make a copy. Because a data.frame is just a pointer to a list of columns, forDT and df point to the same thing, which is modified by `set*`.